# ApproximateMessageCount always null after calling FetchAttributesAsync in a Universal windows App

Tags: azure, win-universal-app, azure-queues

I am making a small App that should list the number of items in my Azure queues.
When I use FetchAttributesAsync and ApproximateMessageCount in a Console App, I get the expected result in ApproximateMessageCount after a call to FetchAttributesAsync (or FetchAttributes).

When I use the same in a Universal Windows app, ApproximateMessageCount remains stuck at `null` after a call to FetchAttributesAsync (FetchAttributes is not available there).

Console code:

```
        CloudStorageAccount _account;

        if (CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(_connectionstring, out _account))
        {
            var queueClient = _account.CreateCloudQueueClient();

            Console.WriteLine(" {0}", _account.QueueEndpoint);
            Console.WriteLine(" ----------------------------------------------");

            var queues = (await queueClient.ListQueuesSegmentedAsync(null)).Results;

            foreach (CloudQueue q in queues)
            {
                await q.FetchAttributesAsync();
                Console.WriteLine($" {q.Name,-40} {q.ApproximateMessageCount,5}");
            }
        }
```

Universal App code:

```
        IEnumerable<CloudQueue> queues;
        CloudStorageAccount _account;
        CloudQueueClient queueClient;

        CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(connectionstring, out _account);
        queueClient = _account.CreateCloudQueueClient();

        queues = (await queueClient.ListQueuesSegmentedAsync(null)).Results;

        foreach (CloudQueue q in queues)
        {
            await q.FetchAttributesAsync();

            var count = q.ApproximateMessageCount;

            // count is always null here!!!
        }
```

I have tried all kinds of alternatives, like Wait()'s and such on the awaitables. Whatever I try, the `ApproximateMessageCount` stays a `null` with dertermination :-(.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have discovered a bug in the storage client library. I looked up the code on Github and essentially instead of reading the value for `Approximate Message Count` header, the code is reading the value for `Lease Status` header.

In [`QueueHttpResponseParsers.cs`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/WindowsRuntime/Queue/Protocol/QueueHttpResponseParsers.cs) class:

```
    public static string GetApproximateMessageCount(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        return response.Headers.GetHeaderSingleValueOrDefault(Constants.HeaderConstants.LeaseStatus);
    }
```

This method should have been:

```
    public static string GetApproximateMessageCount(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        return response.Headers.GetHeaderSingleValueOrDefault(Constants.HeaderConstants.ApproximateMessagesCount);
    }
```

I have submitted a bug for this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/155.